# Delaying http response in angular using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have interceptor responsible for adding access token to the HTTP request header. In that interceptor, I wish to add some asynchronous operation with regard to the response. To keep things simple I'll demonstrate asynchronously using rxjs interval operator:

```
    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
  ((source: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
    return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>((sub: Subscriber<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
      source.subscribe((
        response: HttpEvent<any>) => interval(1000).subscribe(() => sub.next(response)),
        err => sub.error(err),
        () => sub.complete());
    });
  })
);
```

I expect to see a 1-second delay in handling the response, but overall the app should work fine. But it doesn't. It seems like Angular tries to send the request over and over again. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why do you use such a complex thing, including an interval (which emits **every** second: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) just to add a delay? Why not just use the delay operator? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay: `return next.handle(authReq).pipe(delay(1000))`. Why introduce a delay? What do you **really** want to achieve?

Comment: Guys, I specifically said the delay is just a test case. I don't want to implement a delay I want to implement an operator which doesn't further the response in the stream until another observable emits a value.

Comment: Then use something like `return zip(next.handle(authReq), otherObservable).pipe(map(array => array[0]))`.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me since the other async process will start only if the response has some value. Can somebody explain why the example above doesn't work? Knowing that will help me the most.

Answer (score 1):

You are using interval operator. It will fire an event after every nth period of time. If you want to just delay, then use [delay](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay) operator

Comment: Guys, I specifically said the delay is just a test case. I don't want to implement a delay I want to implement an operator which doesn't further the response in the stream until another observable emits a value.